# How to access subdataframes of pandas groupby by key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How do I access the corresponding groupby dataframe in a groupby object by the key?

With the following groupby:

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                   'B': rand.randn(6),
                   'C': rand.randint(0, 20, 6)})
gb = df.groupby(['A'])
```

I can iterate through it to get the keys and groups:

```
In [11]: for k, gp in gb:
             print 'key=' + str(k)
             print gp
key=bar
     A         B   C
1  bar -0.611756  18
3  bar -1.072969  10
5  bar -2.301539  18
key=foo
     A         B   C
0  foo  1.624345   5
2  foo -0.528172  11
4  foo  0.865408  14
```

I would like to be able to access a group by its key:

```
In [12]: gb['foo']
Out[12]:  
     A         B   C
0  foo  1.624345   5
2  foo -0.528172  11
4  foo  0.865408  14
```

But when I try doing that with `gb[('foo',)]` I get this weird `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object thing which doesn't seem to have any methods that correspond to the DataFrame I want.

The best I could think of is:

```
In [13]: def gb_df_key(gb, key, orig_df):
             ix = gb.indices[key]
             return orig_df.ix[ix]

         gb_df_key(gb, 'foo', df)
Out[13]:
     A         B   C
0  foo  1.624345   5
2  foo -0.528172  11
4  foo  0.865408  14
```

but this is kind of nasty, considering how nice pandas usually is at these things.
What's the built-in way of doing this?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use the [`get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.get_group.html?highlight=get_group#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.get_group) method:

```
In [21]: gb.get_group('foo')
Out[21]: 
     A         B   C
0  foo  1.624345   5
2  foo -0.528172  11
4  foo  0.865408  14
```

*Note: This doesn't require creating an intermediary dictionary / copy of every subdataframe for every group, so will be much more memory-efficient than creating the naive dictionary with `dict(iter(gb))`. This is because it uses data-structures already available in the groupby object.*

---

You can select different columns using the groupby slicing:

```
In [22]: gb[["A", "B"]].get_group("foo")
Out[22]:
     A         B
0  foo  1.624345
2  foo -0.528172
4  foo  0.865408

In [23]: gb["C"].get_group("foo")
Out[23]:
0     5
2    11
4    14
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This method is deprecated, any suggestions? The method the docs now recommend didn't work for me.

Comment: @YogeshRiyat Works fine on 2.1.0 for me. Docs say the `obj` parameter is deprecated, not the method itself.

Answer (score 88):

Wes McKinney (pandas' author) in Python for Data Analysis provides the following recipe:

```
groups = dict(list(gb))
```

which returns a dictionary whose keys are your group labels and whose values are DataFrames, i.e.

```
groups['foo']
```

will yield what you are looking for:

```
     A         B   C
0  foo  1.624345   5
2  foo -0.528172  11
4  foo  0.865408  14
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. How can I modify the code to make  `groups = dict(list(gb))` only store column `C`? Let's say I am not interested in the other columns and therefore do not want to store them.

Comment: Answer: `dict(list( df.groupby(['A'])['C'] ))`

Comment: Note: it's more efficient (but equivalent) to use `dict(iter(g))`. (although `get_group` is the best way / as it doesn't involve creating a dictionary / keeps you in pandas! :D )

Comment: I wasn't able to use groups(dict(list(gb)) but you can create a dictionary the following way: `gb_dict = {str(indx): str(val) for indx in gb.indx for val in gb.some_key}` and then retrieve value via `gb_dict[some_key]`

Comment: Just use [`get_group()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.14.0.html?highlight=get_group) , this recipe has not been needed for years.

Answer (score 28):

Rather than

```
gb.get_group('foo')
```

I prefer using `gb.groups`

```
df.loc[gb.groups['foo']]
```

Because in this way you can choose multiple columns as well. for example:

```
df.loc[gb.groups['foo'],('A','B')]
```

Comment: Note: You can select different columns using `gb[["A", "B"]].get_group("foo")`.

Answer (score 8):

```
gb = df.groupby(['A'])

gb_groups = grouped_df.groups
```

If you are looking for selective groupby objects then, do: gb_groups.keys(), and input desired key into the following key_list..

```
gb_groups.keys()

key_list = [key1, key2, key3 and so on...]

for key, values in gb_groups.items():
    if key in key_list:
        print(df.ix[values], "\n")
```

Comment: .iteritems() is for Python 2 (which is dead), so I have changed this answer for Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a way to sample a few members of the GroupBy obj - had to address the posted question to get this done.

#### create groupby object based on `some_key` column

```
grouped = df.groupby('some_key')
```

#### pick N dataframes and grab their indices

```
sampled_df_i  = random.sample(grouped.indices, N)
```

#### grab the groups

```
df_list  = map(lambda df_i: grouped.get_group(df_i), sampled_df_i)
```

#### optionally - turn it all back into a single dataframe object

```
sampled_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, join='outer')
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `sampled_df_i  = random.sample(grouped.indicies, N)`

Comment: @irene - can you provide a link to a longer example/more context?

Comment: I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'indicies'`

Comment: you need `random.sample(sorted(grouped.indices), k=N)`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby('A').get_group('foo')
```

is equivalent to:

```
df[df['A'] == 'foo']
```