# Get specific element from Groups after applying groupby - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have grouped sum data in a dataframe, by the following:

```
groups = df.groupby(['name'])
```

Now I can get the head of the groups by groups.head(2) which gives the first two rows.

But how do I get a group by a specific name? i.e. if I want the single group where the group name is 'ruby', I can't just do groups['ruby']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
groups.get_group('name')
```

For more elaboration, [see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14734533/263858)

Comment: You should provide an explanation, else people may misunderstand your reasoning, and mark your answer as 'low-quality'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @NewAlexandria.  What would you add to a one-liner like this?  Link to the docs?  I think [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key) is more complete than I could hope to be.

Comment: I usually just write something like "it sounds like you're trying to do X, and so ...." or "i looks like this is just a regular call based on the YYY standard lib."  That way, if your assumptions are off, it's more transparent.  Particularly where someone, 2 yr form now, may have slightly different assumptions — your errata will be clarifying.

Comment: Actually, seeing that other answer, I would have just marked this a dupe.  At least you got some rep in before the door was closed :)