# Sampling a grouped dataframe by column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe which I am grouping as follows and applying certain operations to particular columns:

```
 df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg({'ID': 'count', 'AMT': 'sum'})
```

For each groupby combination (~15) I want to randomly sample the rows belonging to each combination and return a sample ID and report it in a third output column. OR I really just want one of the IDs from the rows in that combination to appear in the table, I don't care if it is 'random' or not.

I have tried the following:

```
 df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg({'ID': 'count', 'AMT': 'sum', 'ID': 'sample'})
```

and received the error:

```
 AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sample' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

So I then tried:

```
 func = lambda x: x.sample
 df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg({'ID': 'count', 'AMT': 'sum', 'ID': apply(func)})
```

which didnt work so I tried

```
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg({'ID': 'count', 'AMT': 'sum', 'ID': lambda x: x.sample})
```

which also didn't work. I have reviewed the following links for related questions but they did not seem to help me either.

[Select multiple groups from pandas groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535442/select-multiple-groups-from-pandas-groupby-object)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

[Get specific element from Groups after applying groupby - PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690079/get-specific-element-from-groups-after-applying-groupby-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to access pandas groupby dataframe by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key)

https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_dataframes.html

Any thoughts on how to handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with the code you tried to use.

- `lambda x: x.sample` returns the *function* itself instead of calling it (do `lambda x: x.sample()`).
- `x.sample()` returns a `Series` object. `.agg()` excepts a single scalar value or a list, so that causes an exception. You could do `x.sample().tolist()` but now you have a list instead of a single value. It's more convenient to use `numpy.random.choice()` here.
- Specifying the same column multiple times in the dictionary passed to `.agg()` does not work. Only the last one is going to stick. Assign the functions you want to use as a list or dict to that column instead.

Taking the above into consideration, you'll reach this solution:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg({'ID': ('count', np.random.choice), 'AMT': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the example dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('x'*8 + 'y'*8 + 'z'*8) * 2,
        B=list('x'*4 + 'y'*4 + 'z'*4) * 4,
        C=list('x'*2 + 'y'*2 + 'z'*2) * 8,
        ID=range(48),
        AMT=np.random.rand(48)
    ))

print(df)

    A       AMT  B  C  ID
0   x  0.444939  x  x   0
1   x  0.407554  x  x   1
2   x  0.460148  x  y   2
3   x  0.465239  x  y   3
4   x  0.462691  y  z   4
5   x  0.016545  y  z   5
6   x  0.850445  y  x   6
7   x  0.817744  y  x   7
8   y  0.777962  z  y   8
9   y  0.757983  z  y   9
...
39  y  0.778883  x  y  39
40  z  0.651676  y  z  40
41  z  0.136097  y  z  41
42  z  0.544838  y  x  42
43  z  0.035073  y  x  43
44  z  0.275079  z  y  44
45  z  0.706685  z  y  45
46  z  0.713614  z  z  46
47  z  0.776050  z  z  47
```

## Solution `#1`

You can use `np.random.choice` to pick one

```
f = dict(
    ID=dict(Count='count', Sample=np.random.choice),
    AMT=dict(Sum='sum', Max='max', Min='min')
)

df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg(f)

            AMT                         ID      
            Sum       Max       Min Sample Count
A B C                                           
x x x  2.458188  0.866059  0.407554     25     4
    y  1.993843  0.691271  0.377185     27     4
  y x  3.070036  0.850445  0.700900      7     4
    z  1.139663  0.462691  0.016545     28     4
y x x  2.824838  0.926879  0.253200     13     4
    y  2.166114  0.778883  0.117642     39     4
  z y  2.351120  0.796487  0.018688      8     4
    z  3.367248  0.934829  0.700566     10     4
z y x  1.118176  0.544838  0.035073     19     4
    z  1.133523  0.651676  0.136097     16     4
  z y  1.870361  0.706685  0.275079     44     4
    z  2.412484  0.836997  0.085823     47     4
```

## Solution `#2`

pick more than 1

You can use `pd.DataFrame.sample` to take whole slices of `df`

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=2)

          A       AMT  B  C  ID
A B C                          
x x x 25  x  0.866059  x  x  25
      0   x  0.444939  x  x   0
    y 26  x  0.691271  x  y  26
      27  x  0.377185  x  y  27
  y x 6   x  0.850445  y  x   6
      31  x  0.700946  y  x  31
    z 28  x  0.225146  y  z  28
      29  x  0.435280  y  z  29
y x x 13  y  0.926879  x  x  13
      37  y  0.253200  x  x  37
    y 38  y  0.548054  x  y  38
      39  y  0.778883  x  y  39
  z y 33  y  0.018688  z  y  33
      32  y  0.796487  z  y  32
    z 11  y  0.831104  z  z  11
      10  y  0.934829  z  z  10
z y x 42  z  0.544838  y  x  42
      43  z  0.035073  y  x  43
    z 41  z  0.136097  y  z  41
      17  z  0.199844  y  z  17
  z y 20  z  0.278735  z  y  20
      45  z  0.706685  z  y  45
    z 22  z  0.085823  z  z  22
      47  z  0.776050  z  z  47
```

Answer (score 0):

given that you aggregate using `agg`, you must return a single element. So you can try using

`'ID': lambda x: x.sample.tolist()`