# GroupBy results to dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

I have an excel sheet that looks like so:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
0       23      1
1       5       2
1       2       3
1       19      5
2       56      1
2       22      2
3       2       4
3       14      5
4       59      1
5       44      1
5       1       2
5       87      3
```

And I'm looking to extract that data, group it by column 1, and add it to a dictionary so it appears like this:

```
{0: [1],
1: [2,3,5],
2: [1,2],
3: [4,5],
4: [1],
5: [1,2,3]}
```

This is my code so far

```
excel = pandas.read_excel(r"e:\test_data.xlsx", sheetname='mySheet', parse_cols'A,C')
myTable = excel.groupby("Column1").groups
print myTable
```

However, my output looks like this:

```
{0: [0L], 1: [1L, 2L, 3L], 2: [4L, 5L], 3: [6L, 7L], 4: [8L], 5: [9L, 10L, 11L]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: for easy test, I add sample dataframe code. data = {
    'col1': [0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5], 
    'col2': np.random.randint(0, 55, 12),
    'col3': [1,2,3,5,1,2,4,5,1,1,2,3]
    } and df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Related (not duplicate) : [How to access subdataframes of pandas groupby by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-subdataframes-of-pandas-groupby-by-key)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could `groupby` on `Column1` and then take `Column3` to `apply(list)` and call `to_dict`?

```
In [81]: df.groupby('Column1')['Column3'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[81]: {0: [1], 1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1, 2], 3: [4, 5], 4: [1], 5: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Or, do

```
In [433]: {k: list(v) for k, v in df.groupby('Column1')['Column3']}
Out[433]: {0: [1], 1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1, 2], 3: [4, 5], 4: [1], 5: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Bit mean to accept this answer when @EdChum's is identical and was posted 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: What is the optimal way to do this for multiple features ie: Column1 is the consistent key  but inplace of Column3, it can have Column4, Column5 and then merge so that Column1 still remains as a key to the dict.

Comment: wow man, your name should be Hero not Zero

Comment: what if I want to have `column2` and `column3`? stored on a dictionary, but also preserving its colnames?

Answer (score 50):

According to [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes), the `GroupBy.groups`:

> is a dict whose keys are the computed unique groups and corresponding
>   values being the *axis labels* belonging to each group.

If you want the values themselves, you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) 'Column1' and then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) and pass the `list` method to apply to each group.

You can then convert it to a dict as desired:

```
In [5]:

dict(df.groupby('Column1')['Column3'].apply(list))
Out[5]:
{0: [1], 1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1, 2], 3: [4, 5], 4: [1], 5: [1, 2, 3]}
```

*(Note: have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix) for why the numbers are followed by `L`)*