# Grouping column values into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe of the following structure:

```
   Name   Desc   Group ConditionType ConditionName
0  job1  desc1  group1            in         cond1
1  job1  desc1  group1            in         cond2
2  job1  desc1  group1           out         cond1
3  job2  desc2  group1            in         cond1
4  job2  desc2  group1            in         cond2
5  job2  desc2  group1            in         cond3
```

For the context, it's a full join of two tables; one with `Name`, `Desc` and `Group` columns and the other with `ConditionType` and `ConditionName` columns. The tables are joined on the column `Name`.

I would like to organize this DataFrame, such that I have the following structure:

```
   Name   Desc   Group                                      Conditions
0  job1  desc1  group1    {'in': ['cond1', 'cond2'], 'out': ['cond1']}
1  job2  desc2  group1  {'in': ['cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3'], 'out': []}
```

I am looking for a faster way to do this (possibly using `groupby()` and `apply()`) just not sure where to start. For-loop is really slow since the original table is over 100000 records.

Here's the code to instantiate both the initial table and the result that I seek:

```
table = [['job1', 'desc1', 'group1', 'in', 'cond1'],
         ['job1', 'desc1', 'group1', 'in', 'cond2'],
         ['job1', 'desc1', 'group1', 'out', 'cond1'],
         ['job2', 'desc2', 'group1', 'in', 'cond1'],
         ['job2', 'desc2', 'group1', 'in', 'cond2'],
         ['job2', 'desc2', 'group1', 'in', 'cond3']]

result = [['job1', 'desc1', 'group1', {'in': ['cond1', 'cond2'], 'out': ['cond1']}],
          ['job2', 'desc2', 'group1', {'in': ['cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3'], 'out': []}]]

table_df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Name', 'Desc', 'Group', 'ConditionType', 'ConditionName'])
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Name', 'Desc', 'Group', 'Conditions'])
```

Comment: Would this work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876208/702383 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a `pandas` way, but this is the intuitive way via row iteration and `collections.defaultdict`.

Note there are couple of minor adjustments you may wish to make (resetting index, adding empty dictionary items).

A `groupby` method will not *necessarily* be faster. You should test with your data. For performance, use `df.itertuples` instead of `df.iterrows`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    d[(row.Name, row.Desc, row.Group)][row.ConditionType].append(row.ConditionName)

df['Conditions'] = df.set_index(['Name', 'Desc', 'Group']).index.map(d.get)

df = df.loc[:, ['Name', 'Desc', 'Group', 'Conditions']]\
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Desc', 'Group'])

print(df)

#    Name   Desc   Group                                    Conditions
# 0  job1  desc1  group1  {'in': ['cond1', 'cond2'], 'out': ['cond1']}
# 3  job2  desc2  group1           {'in': ['cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3']}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me; and takes reasonable amount of time for the use case.