# Taking a list of data frames and grouping by a variable and using that variable as the key to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am relatively new to python programming. I have a list of pandas dataframes that all have the column 'Year'. I am trying to group by that column and convert to a dictionary where the dictionary key is the variable 'Year' and values is a list of dataframes of that year. Is this possible in python?

I tried this:

```
grouped_dict = list_of_csv_files.groupby(by = 'Year').to_dict()
```

I believe I will have to loop through each dataframe? I did not provide any data because I am hoping it is a somewhat simple solution.

I also tried this:

```
grouped_dict = list_of_csv_files.groupby(by = 'Year').apply(lambda dfg: dfg.to_dict(orient='list')).to_dict()
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried: `grouped_dict = {k: v for k, v in list_of_csv_files.groupby('Year')}` ?

Comment: I get this warning: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: you probably want use `pd.concat` on that list then to build a single dataframe before applying groupby on it... Possibly something like: `pd.concat(list_of_csv_files).groupby('Year')` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have missed the mark so far, so I'll give you an alternative. Assuming you have CSV files (since your variable is named that way):

```
from collections import defaultdict

yearly_dfs = defaultdict(list)
for csv in list_of_csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    for yr, yr_df in df.groupby("Year"):
        yearly_dfs[yr].append(yr_df)
```

Assuming you have DataFrames already:

```
from collections import defaultdict

yearly_dfs = defaultdict(list)
for df in list_of_csv_files:
    for yr, yr_df in df.groupby("Year"):
        yearly_dfs[yr].append(yr_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should read the files into a single dataframe:

`list_of_dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False) for filename in list_of_csv_files]
df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, sort=True)`

Then apply the groupby transformation on the dataframe and convert it into a dictionary:

`grouped_dict = df.groupby('Year').apply(list).to_dict()`

This question is a duplicate of [GroupBy results to dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876184/groupby-results-to-dictionary-of-lists)

Comment: I get this warning: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'