# How to add two category lists to dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe

```
df =
          name     age     character
0          A        10       fire
1          A        15       water
2          A        20       earth
3          A        25       air
4          B        10       fire
5          B        7        air
```

I want to convert this dataframe to dictionary, so that output will be,

```
dic = {'A': [[10, 15, 20, 25], ['fire', 'water', 'earth', 'air']],
       'B': [[10, 7], ['fire', 'air']] }
```

What I tried is,

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(df)):
    dic[df.loc['name', i]].append(df.loc['age', i])
    dic[df.loc['name', i]].append(df.loc['character', i]) # this is wrong. It appends to existing list.
```

If I declare `dic = defaultdict([[], []])`, it throws error that first argument of defaultdict must be callable or None.
How can I improve this dictionary?

Comment: `dic = {'A': [10, 15, 20, 25], ['fire', 'water', 'earth', 'air'],
       'B': [10, 7], ['fire', 'air'] }` makes no sense.

Comment: The `dic` you provided is an invalid Python `dict`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split pandas dataframe based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby)

Comment: @Błotosmętek Just found my mistake and fixed it.

Comment: @noslenkwah it is similar. Can groupby pandas df be converted to dictionary?

Comment: @jayko03 - [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876184/groupby-results-to-dictionary-of-lists)

Comment: @noslenkwah I don't see use case of groupby to dictionary.

Comment: The title of the question is "GroupBy results to dictionary of lists". I'm not sure what to tell you except to read over the questions and answers again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use combination of `pivot_table` and `to_dict`

```
dic = (df.pivot_table(columns='name', values=['age','character'], aggfunc=list)
         .to_dict('l'))

Out[107]:
{'A': [[10, 15, 20, 25], ['fire', 'water', 'earth', 'air']],
 'B': [[10, 7], ['fire', 'air']]}
```

If you dataframe have exact 3 columns `name`, `age`, `character`, you may simply ignore `values=` parameter

```
dic = df.pivot_table(columns='name', aggfunc=list).to_dict('l')
```

---

As you said in comment, to strip whitespaces, you need to pre-process `df` with `str.strip` before calling `pivot_table` as follows

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()))
dic = df.pivot_table(columns='name', aggfunc=list).to_dict('l')
```

Comment: This is very nice and works great. Is it possible to strip on keys and values?

Comment: @jayko03: could you explain more on what `keys` and `values` you want to strip?

Comment: For example, the key  can be 'A ', or the value can be ['fire ', ' water'] .. something like this white space

Comment: @jayko03:  ah, I understand now. You want to strip white spaces from values and keys. Just do `str.strip` on columns of `df` before calling `pivot_table`

Comment: @jayko03: check my updated answer for stripping whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that returns `np.array`, which is similar enough to `list`:

```
{k: d[['age','character']].T.to_numpy() for k,d in df.groupby('name')}
```

Output:

```
{'A': array([[10, 15, 20, 25],
        ['fire', 'water', 'earth', 'air']], dtype=object), 
'B': array([[10, 7],
        ['fire', 'air']], dtype=object)}
```