# functional way of creating defaultdict[list]?

Tags: python-3.x

Basically I've found this and similar code a bunch of times now:

```
items_by_parent = defaultdict(list)
for item in items:
    items_by_parent[item.parent].append(item)
```

I come from a C# background and was a heavy linq user where you'd go `list.GroupBy(...).ToDictionary(...)`, so this snippet grinds my gears to some extent. Which leads me to ask: **Is there some functional way to achieve the same result in python**?

Thanks :)

Comment: The only thing similar to this would be using Pandas API, and it would look something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876239/1737811

Comment: What kind of object is an `item`?

Comment: If you had a list of possible `parent`s you could use a dict-comprehension, but the code above is definitely more efficient