# Pandas: map column using a dictionary on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with `None` values in one column. I would like to replace this `None` values with the maximum value of the "category" for the same combination of other columns.

Example: pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'company': ['Company1', 'Company1', 'Company1', 'Company1', 'Company2', 'Company2'], 'product': ['Product A', 'Product A', 'Product F', 'Product A', 'Product F', 'Product F'], 'category': ['1', None, '3', '2', None, '5']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

   company   product       category
0  Company1  Product A        1
1  Company1  Product A     None
2  Company1  Product F        3
3  Company1  Product A        2
4  Company2  Product F     None
5  Company2  Product F        5
```

I want to replace the `None` values in 3. column with the max() value of this column for the unique combination (group of 1. + 2. column).
The expected result would look like this:

```
   company   product       category
0  Company1  Product A        1
1  Company1  Product A        **2**
2  Company1  Product F        3
3  Company1  Product A        2
4  Company2  Product F        **5**
5  Company2  Product F        5
```

What I've tried:
I've grouped the 1. + 2. column ("company + product") + get the max() of the 3. column + build a dictionary 'category'. (based on the idea of [GroupBy results to dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876184/groupby-results-to-dictionary-of-lists))

```
df_dict = df[~df['category'].isna()].groupby(['company','product'])['category'].max().apply(list).to_dict()
```

and I get this dict `df_dict` (shows the maximum category value for each combination):

```
{('Company1', 'Product A'): ['2'], ('Company1', 'Product F'): ['1'], ('Company2', 'Product F'): ['5']}
```

Now I want to replace `None` with the max values for each combination from my dcitionary

```
df[df['category'].isna()]

   ompany    product       category
1  Company1  Product A     None
4  Company2  Product F     None
```

The question, how can I do it?
I tried with `set_index()`

```
df[df['category'].isna()].set_index(['company', 'product']).index
```

results in

```
MultiIndex([('Company1', 'Product A'),
        ('Company2', 'Product F')],
       names=['company', 'product'])
```

which would fit the entry in the dictionary and use it together `map()`

```
    df['category'] = df[df['category'].isna()].set_index(['company', 'product']).in
dex.map(df_dict)
```

... but I get an ValueError

```
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (6)
```

Comment: very good question btw with a great reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps:

First, let's turn those None values to `NaNs` so we can use numeric operations.

```
df['category'] = pd.to_numeric(df['category']) # add arg ,errors='coerce' if needed.
```

Second, let's use groupby transform and max to fill only the NaN values:

```
df["category"] = df["category"].fillna(
    df.groupby(["company", "product"])["category"].transform("max")
)
print(df)

    company    product  category
0  Company1  Product A       1.0
1  Company1  Product A       2.0
2  Company1  Product F       3.0
3  Company1  Product A       2.0
4  Company2  Product F       5.0
5  Company2  Product F       5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your help. It solved the problem. +1

Comment: I have another table almost same problem. But there is an additional colum with strings. I will add this case to the question on the top.