# find highest value in group, and add value of other column to a new row in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the table:

| person | score | Job type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| person 1 | 6.5 | job 1 |
| person 1 | 4.3 | job 2 |
| person 2 | 1.2 | job 1 |
| person 2 | 3.4 | job 2 |
| person 2 | 4.3 | job 3 |

i want to ad a column with the job type, with highest score, like this:

| person | score | Job type | Higest score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person 1 | 6.5 | job 1 | job 1 |
| person 1 | 4.3 | job 2 | job 1 |
| person 2 | 1.2 | job 1 | job 3 |
| person 2 | 3.4 | job 2 | job 3 |
| person 3 | 4.3 | job 3 | job 3 |

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: map column using max() value of another colum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336010/pandas-map-column-using-max-value-of-another-colum)

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be as follows:

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `person`, and get [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for column `score`, wrapped inside [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).
- Use the result inside [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select the correct entries from `Job type`, and add [`Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) to keep only the values (dropping the index values, which won't match).
- Assign to the new column.

```
df['Highest score'] = df.loc[df.groupby('person')['score'].transform('idxmax'),
                             'Job type'].to_numpy()

print(df)

     person  score Job type Highest score
0  person 1    6.5    job 1         job 1
1  person 1    4.3    job 2         job 1
2  person 2    1.2    job 1         job 3
3  person 2    3.4    job 2         job 3
4  person 2    4.3    job 3         job 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's sort the data by score. Then let's group by person and get the last value of each group. The last value is the highest value:

```
mask=df.sort_values('score').groupby('person').tail(1).rename(columns={'Job type':'Higest_score'})

final=df.merge(mask[['person','Higest_score']],how='left')
final
'''
    person      score   Job type    Higest_score
0   person 1    6.5     job 1       job 1
1   person 1    4.3     job 2       job 1
2   person 2    1.2     job 1       job 3
3   person 2    3.4     job 2       job 3
4   person 2    4.3     job 3       job 3

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('person')['score'].transform(lambda x:df.loc[x.idxmax(), 'Job type'])
```

result:

```
0    job 1
1    job 1
2    job 3
3    job 3
4    job 3
Name: score, dtype: object
```

make result to `Higest score` column

Answer (score 0):

With `merge()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'person': ['person 1', 'person 1', 'person 2', 'person 2', 'person 2'], 'score': [6.5, 4.3, 1.2, 3.4, 4.3],
     'Job type': ['job 1', 'job 2', 'job 1', 'job 2', 'job 3']})

df = df.merge(df.loc[df.groupby('person', as_index=False).score.idxmax().score, ['person', 'Job type']], on='person',
              how='right', suffixes=('', '_')).rename(columns={'Job type_': 'Higest score'})
print(df)
```

```
     person  score Job type Higest score
0  person 1    6.5    job 1        job 1
1  person 1    4.3    job 2        job 1
2  person 2    1.2    job 1        job 3
3  person 2    3.4    job 2        job 3
4  person 2    4.3    job 3        job 3
```