# Create a dictionary with keys that have between 1-5 unique values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a DataFrame with a column of player NAMES and a column of player unique IDs. There may be more than one player with the same name (i.e. John Williams), but two unique player IDs (i.e. williamsjo01 & williamsjo02). When I create a dictionary of the two columns, where ever there is a key with multiple values, it only captures the latter value.

I am looking for a way for the keys with multiple values to be a list with multiple values. What I am thinking right now is possibly using a conditional statement such as:

```
if df['fullName'].value_counts() > 1:
    (creates list and appends multiple values to one key)
else:
    dict(zip(df['fullName'], df['playerID']
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You want to do a `groupby` first and then dict that, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876184/groupby-results-to-dictionary-of-lists

Comment: Thanks that was just what I was looking for! Forgot about the groupby.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"NAME":['A','A','B','B','C'],
                   "ID":[1, 2, 1, 2,1]})

temp1 = df['NAME'].unique()
lis1 = temp1.tolist()
print(lis1)

temp2 = df['NAME'].value_counts()
lis2 = temp2.to_list()
print(lis2)


d = dict(zip(lis1, lis2))
for key, value in d.items():
  if value > 1:
      lis3 = df.loc[df['NAME'] == key, 'ID'].unique().tolist()
      d[key] = lis3

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 2], 'C': 1}
```