# How to create Dictionary from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create dictionary from a pandas data-frame of the users for the books that the user has read.

| User | Book |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | book1 |
| user 2 | book1 |
| user1 | book2 |
| user1 | book3 |
| user2 | book3 |
| user2 | book2 |

Expected result:

```
{
    user1: book 1, book2, book3...
    user2: book1, book3, book2...
    ...
}
```

Comment: You could have searched Stack Overflow and found that duplicate and many others, or even just looked at [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: You can see in  Stack Overflow and found that duplicate questions.

Comment: `d = df.groupby('User')['Book'].agg(list).to_dict()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876239/15497888) seems like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` to find users based on unique values:

```
total_users = list(df['User'].unique())  #find unique users

final_dict = {}
for usr in total_users:
    final_dict[usr] = df.loc[df['User']==usr,'Book'].tolist()
print(final_dict)
```