# Pandas group by column and convert to key:value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

I want to convert DataFrame using pandas.

I would like to convert it into dictionary format like `{'Plant Delivering ID': [Ship-To ID]}`

there are multiple **'Ship-To ID'** for single **'Plant Delivering ID'**

My Original Data Format:

[image: Original Data Format]

I would like to convert it to:

[image: converted Data Format]

How do I convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then get the result of groupby with `apply(list)` at the end convert the result to dict with [`pandas.Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html).

```
df.groupby('Plant Delivering ID')['Ship-To-ID'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby then zip columns wrapped in dict()

```
df = df.groupby("Plant Delivering ID")["Ship-To-ID"].apply(list).reset_index()
df_dict = dict(zip(df["Plant Delivering ID"], df["Ship-To-ID"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could perform a `group by` on the Plant Delivering ID and bring everything into a `dictionary`.

Something like this:

```py
dict = {k: list(v) for k, v in df.groupby('Plant Delivering ID')['Ship-To ID']}
```

Hope it helps!

The code is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876184/groupby-results-to-dictionary-of-lists) old answer.