# Select multiple groups from pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I am experimenting with the groupby features of pandas, in particular

```
gb = df.groupby('model')
gb.hist()
```

Since gb has 50 groups the result is quite cluttered, I would like to explore the result only for the first 5 groups.

I found how to select a single group with `groups` or `get_group` ([How to access pandas groupby dataframe by key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14734533/1136458)), but not how to select multiple groups directly.
The best I could do is :

```
groups = dict(list(gb))
subgroup = pd.concat(groups.values()[:4])
subgroup.groupby('model').hist()
```

Is there a more direct way?

Comment: Selecting the first n groups is a bit vague, perhaps you mean **how can you join the first n groups into a single dataframe**.. something along those lines ? And also, how would you like to select the groups ? Randomly , or according to the population of the group , etc?

Comment: For now I would just select them by their order, a bit like using head() or tail() just for having an idea of how the data looks like. I think my method is already joining the first groups in a single dataframe, but it would be nice also a more efficient solution

Comment: you can get the groups by just calling `gp.groups` see:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups you may be better off just filtering your df first so `df_filt = df[df['model'].isin(df['model'].unique()[:5])]` then `gb = df_filt.groupby('model')` #rest of code is the same as before

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like

```
new_gb = pandas.concat( [ gb.get_group(group) for i,group in enumerate( gb.groups) if i < 5 ] ).groupby('model')    
new_gb.hist()
```

Although, I would approach it differently. You can use the `collections.Counter` object to get groups fast:

```
import collections

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'model': pandas.np.random.randint(0, 3, 10), 'param1': pandas.np.random.random(10), 'param2':pandas.np.random.random(10)})
#   model    param1    param2
#0      2  0.252379  0.985290
#1      1  0.059338  0.225166
#2      0  0.187259  0.808899
#3      2  0.773946  0.696001
#4      1  0.680231  0.271874
#5      2  0.054969  0.328743
#6      0  0.734828  0.273234
#7      0  0.776684  0.661741
#8      2  0.098836  0.013047
#9      1  0.228801  0.827378
model_groups = collections.Counter(df.model)
print(model_groups) #Counter({2: 4, 0: 3, 1: 3})
```

Now you can iterate over the `Counter` object like a dictionary, and query the groups you want:

```
new_df = pandas.concat( [df.query('model==%d'%key) for key,val in model_groups.items() if val < 4 ] ) # for example, but you can select the models however you like  
#   model    param1    param2
#2      0  0.187259  0.808899
#6      0  0.734828  0.273234
#7      0  0.776684  0.661741
#1      1  0.059338  0.225166
#4      1  0.680231  0.271874
#9      1  0.228801  0.827378
```

Now you can use the built-in `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` function

```
gb = new_df.groupby('model')
gb.hist()
```

Since `model_groups` contains all of the groups, you can just pick from it as you wish.

## note

If your `model` column contains string values (names or something) instead of integers, it will all work the same - just change the query argument from `'model==%d'%key` to `'model=="%s"'%key`.

Answer (score 11):

It'd be easier to just filter your df first and then perform the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [155]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'model':np.random.randint(1,10,100), 'value':np.random.randn(100)})
first_five = df['model'].sort(inplace=False).unique()[:5]
gp = df[df['model'].isin(first_five)].groupby('model')
gp.first()
Out[155]:
          value
model          
1     -0.505677
2      1.217027
3     -0.641583
4      0.778104
5     -1.037858
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to use the [`.get_group()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#selecting-a-group) with more than one group.

You can, however, [iterate through groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)

It is still a bit ugly to do this, but here is one solution with iteration:

```py
limit = 5
i = 0
for key, group in gd:
    print(key, group)
    i += 1
    if i >= limit:
        break
```

You could also do a loop with [`.get_group()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html), which imho, is a little prettier, but still quite ugly.

```py
for key in list(gd.groups.keys())[:2]:
    print(gd.get_group(key))
```

Comment: To use .get_group() method with more than one group, you need to pass a Tuple with values for key1 and values for key2 ...

Answer (score 1):

```py
gbidx=list(gb.indices.keys())[:4]
dfidx=np.sort(np.concatenate([gb.indices[x] for x in gbidx]))
df.loc[dfidx].groupby('model').hist()
```

gb.indices is faster than gb.groups or list(gb)

and I believe concat Index is faster than concat DataFrames

I've tried on my big csv file of ~416M rows 13 cols (incl. str) and 720MB in size, and groupby by more than one col

then changed col names into those in the Question

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_groups(group_object):
    for i in group_object.groups.keys():
        print(f"____{i}____")
        display(group_object.get_group(i))


#get all groups by calling this method 

get_groups( any_group_which_you_made )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Posting a code snippet is fine but it's better if you explain how it solves the OP question. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This does NOT get multiple groups at once, irrelevant for the question.