# Group a dataframe based on column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df:
      AAAA   BBBB  CCCC
1111  17878    2    2
2222  17878    2    3
3333  11777    2    4
4444  11888    5    5
```

I have a series below:

```
ser:

17878
11777
```

I want my df to look like thi:

```
df:
      AAAA   BBBB  CCCC
1111  17878    2    2
2222  17878    2    3
3333  11777    2    4
```

This is the code that i found but it does not work with series

```
df.groupby(['AAAA']).get_group(ser)
```

Comment: What you want doesn't appear to be grouping, it's filtering: `df[df['AAAA'].isin(ser)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select multiple groups from pandas groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535442/select-multiple-groups-from-pandas-groupby-object)

Comment: @CodeDifferent yup your right it should be filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work -

```
df = df[df['AAAA'].isin(ser.tolist())]
```