# Dividing a pandas groupby object into chunks

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame that I am grouping by columns ['client', 'product', 'data'].

```
grouped_data = raw_data.groupby(['client', 'product', 'data'])
print(len(grouped_data))
# 10000
```

I want to split the resulting groupby object into two chunks, one containing roughly 80% of the groups, the other one containing the rest.

I have been banging my head against the screen for some time now...

Comment: is it 80% of grouped data , or each group you want to split it to two one 80% and the other 20%

Comment: `groupby` will already divide them into chunks equal to unique data in column `data`

Comment: I need 8000 groups and 2000 groups as the end result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas Choosing Random Sample of Groups from Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340604/python-pandas-choosing-random-sample-of-groups-from-groupby)

Comment: based on some condition or arbitrary division?

Comment: Arbitrary division...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `np.split`

```
df['key']=df[['client', 'product', 'data']].apply(tuple,1)

g1,g2=np.split(df['key'].unique(),[2000])

df1=df[df['key'].isin(g1)]

df2=df[df['key'].isin(g2)]
```

Comment: This is nice, though I prefer `df.set_index([...]).index` for defining groups. I *think* it's faster than `apply` + `tuple`.

Comment: @jpp I am also think that way , maybe using `list + map` can enhance the speed

Comment: Your proposed solution works a treat. How would that other version look roughly?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Client')

bound = int(np.ceil(len(grouped)*0.8))-1

chunk1 = [g[1] for g in list(grouped)[:bound]]
chunk2 = [g[1] for g in list(grouped)[bound:]]
```

For the following sample dataframe:

```
     Client   Product   Data
0   Client1  ProductA  Data1
1   Client2  ProductA  Data3
2   Client3  ProductB  Data1
3   Client4  ProductA  Data2
4   Client5  ProductB  Data1
5   Client2  ProductA  Data1
6   Client3  ProductA  Data3
7   Client2  ProductB  Data1
8   Client3  ProductB  Data1
9   Client5  ProductA  Data2
10  Client1  ProductA  Data1
11  Client1  ProductB  Data1
12  Client4  ProductA  Data2
13  Client3  ProductB  Data2
14  Client2  ProductB  Data3
```

`chunk1` would yield:

```
     Client   Product   Data
0   Client1  ProductA  Data1
10  Client1  ProductA  Data1
11  Client1  ProductB  Data1

     Client   Product   Data
1   Client2  ProductA  Data3
5   Client2  ProductA  Data1
7   Client2  ProductB  Data1
14  Client2  ProductB  Data3

     Client   Product   Data
2   Client3  ProductB  Data1
6   Client3  ProductA  Data3
8   Client3  ProductB  Data1
13  Client3  ProductB  Data2
```

And `chunk2` would yield:

```
     Client   Product   Data
3   Client4  ProductA  Data2
12  Client4  ProductA  Data2

    Client   Product   Data
4  Client5  ProductB  Data1
9  Client5  ProductA  Data2
```