# How to make chunks of rows after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with information about year, month, day, time and other variables (var1, var2, var3 etc). I want to do the following:

(1) Arrange in the ascending order of time

(2) Group together rows with same year, month, and day.

(3) In each group, make chunks of 3 (or N in general) consecutive events and if the last remaining events in that group is < 3, still group them together in a chunk.

E.g.:

```
   year            Month     Day  Time (hr)   var1       var2      var3
       2018            8         17   8.716667  0.152741 -1.647750 -1.605000 
       2018            8         17   8.716667  0.093366  2.000781  1.973152 
       2018            8         17   8.716667  0.239732 -1.663985 -1.698509
       2018            8         17   8.716667  0.184664  1.689448  1.649670     
       2018            8         17   8.716667  0.097565  1.619323  1.645629
```

I would like to have first 3 rows together chunked like this:

```
   2018            8         17   8.716667  0.152741 -1.647750 -1.605000 
   2018            8         17   8.716667  0.093366  2.000781  1.973152 
   2018            8         17   8.716667  0.239732 -1.663985 -1.698509
```

and the next remaining in a separate chunk

```
   2018            8         17   8.716667  0.184664  1.689448  1.649670     
   2018            8         17   8.716667  0.097565  1.619323  1.645629
```

so that I can do further processing in these chunks.

I can do (1) and (2) like this:

```
 df = dfFull.sort_values(by='event_time', ascending=True)
 df = df.groupby([dfFull.event_year,dfFull.event_month,dfFull.event_day])
```

However, I am not sure how to achieve the (3) step.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can just chunk the result by using :
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)] where n is the size of the chunk 

Found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729727/pandas-slice-large-dataframe-into-chunks

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819416/dividing-a-pandas-groupby-object-into-chunks

Comment: Thanks a lot. list_df.append(np.array_split(df.get_group(key), n)) worked perfectly for  my purpose

Answer (score 0):

For (3) you could create a chunk index and the use it for a new grouping:

```py
   df = dfFull.sort_values(by='event_time', ascending=True)
   df['chunkIndex'] = df.groupby([dfFull.event_year,dfFull.event_month,dfFull.event_day]).cumcount() // 3
   df.groupby(['event_year','event_month','event_day', 'chunkIndex'])
```