# Pandas returning empty groups in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 3 columns, `target`, `pred`, and `conf_bin`. If I run a `groupby(by='conf_bin').apply(...)` my apply function gets called with empty `DataFrame`s for values that do not appear in the `conf_bin` column. How is this possible?

---

**Details**

The DataFrame looks something like this:

```
        target  pred conf_bin
0            5     6     0.50
1            4     4     0.60
2            4     4     0.50
3            4     3     0.50
4            4     5     0.50
5            5     5     0.55
6            5     5     0.55
7            5     5     0.55
```

Obviously `conf_bin` is a numeric bin with values in the range `np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)`. However, not all values are present in the data:

```
In [224]: grp = tp.groupby(by='conf_bin')

In [225]: grp.groups.keys()
Out[225]: dict_keys([0.5, 0.60000000000000009, 0.35000000000000003, 0.75, 0.85000000000000009, 0.65000000000000002, 0.55000000000000004, 0.80000000000000004, 0.20000000000000001, 0.45000000000000001, 0.40000000000000002, 0.30000000000000004, 0.70000000000000007, 0.25])
```

So, for example, the values `0` and `0.05` do not appear. However, when I run an `apply` on the group my function does get called for these values:

```
In [226]: grp.apply(lambda x: x.shape)
Out[226]:
conf_bin
0.00        (0, 3)
0.05        (0, 3)
0.10        (0, 3)
0.15        (0, 3)
0.20       (22, 3)
0.25       (75, 3)
0.30       (95, 3)
0.35      (870, 3)
0.40     (8505, 3)
0.45    (40068, 3)
0.50    (51238, 3)
0.55    (54305, 3)
0.60    (47191, 3)
0.65    (38977, 3)
0.70    (34444, 3)
0.75    (20435, 3)
0.80     (3352, 3)
0.85        (4, 3)
0.90        (0, 3)
dtype: object
```

Questions:

1. How can Pandas even know that the values 0.0 and 0.5 "make sense" since they don't appear in my `DataFrame`?
2. Why is it calling my apply function with empty `DataFrame` objects for values that do no appear in `grp.groups`?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data demonstrating the problem?

Comment: what are the `dtypes`.?  Is it possible they are categorical with the information about all the bins in the category spec?

Comment: @piRSquared is correct. The dtype of `conf_bin` is `category`. Thanks!!

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50579578/4755520 for the categorical case. TL;DR use `.groupby(..., observed=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

I too was having this problem, which popped up when trying to create subplots for every category in my dataframe.

I came up with the following workaround (based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key)), by pulling out the non-empty groups into a list.

```
groups = df.groupby('conf_bin')
group_list = [(index, group) for index, group in groups if len(group) > 0]
```

It does break the implicit contract that "you wrangle your data in pandas", and probably mismanages memory, but it works.

---

Now you can iterate through your groupby list with the same interface as with a groupby object, e.g.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(group_list), ncols=1)
for (index, group), ax in zip(group_list, axes.flatten()):
    group['target'].plot(ax=ax, title=index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping column is of categorical type and has information about additional possible groups not in your data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).