# Pandas groupby unique issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'region_group'. As shown below, this dataframe does not have 'ARTHOG' value in 'Town/City' column. However when I do groupby-first, on this column, this value pops back in. I am trying to understand why this is happening.

Note: region_group dataframe is based on another dataframe which has 'ARTHOG' as value in 'Town/City' column. But it has been filtered out with where condition as shown below and as also evident in the Out[25]

```
region=k[['my_ID','Town/City','District','County','month','year']]
region=region.loc[(region['month'] == 12) & (region['year'] == 2016)]
region_noid=region.drop(['my_ID','month','year'], axis=1)

region_group=region_noid.groupby(['Town/City','District','County']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

[image]

Comment: What `dtype` is your "Town/City" column? Just ruling out categoricals.

Comment: No it's a categorical data type.

Comment: region_group.dtypes
Out[29]: 
Town/City    category
District     category
County       category
Count           int64
dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas uses the product of all categorical columns in `groupby` operations to determine the index of the output. This means that even if a category is not represented in the underlying data, it will be represented in `groupby` results.

Details of this, as well as possible solutions, can be found in my question challenging the purpose of this behaviour:
[Pandas groupby with categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471648/pandas-groupby-with-categories)

The pandas development team have [taken the stance](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17594) that all combinations of categories must be representing in `groupby` operations on categorical series.

Answer (score 1):

Category data will carry over the category , when there is no value , will still keeping the category but fill the value as NaN

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,4,5],'B':[1,2,2,2,2]})
df.A=df.A.astype('category',categories=[1,2,3,4,5])

df.groupby('A').B.first()
Out[905]: 
A
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Solution , convert it back to str or numeric

```
df.A=df.A.astype(int)
df.groupby('A').B.first()
Out[907]: 
A
1    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Or we are using `remove_unused_categories`

```
df.A=df.A.cat.remove_unused_categories()
df.groupby('A').B.first()
Out[910]: 
A
1    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: wen and jp_data_analysis. Thanks to both of you. Its great to know this. You both are right and I can accept only one answer. I have accepted jp_data_analysis answer because he answered first. Thanks again.

Comment: @MadhukarJha Let is ok, Let me offer more option to you

Answer (score 0):

Since Pandas 0.23.0, the groupby method can now take a parameter "observed" which fixes this issue if it is set to True (False by default).