# pivot_table requires more memory if dtype is category (MemoryError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following strange error with pandas(pandas==0.23.1) :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'t1': ["a","b","c"]*10000, 't2': ["x","y","z"]*10000, 'i1': list(range(5000))*6, 'i2': list(range(5000))*6, 'dummy':0})
# works fast with less memory
piv = df.pivot_table(values='dummy', index=['i1','i2'], columns=['t1','t2'])

d2 = df.copy()
d2.t1 = d2.t1.astype('category')
d2.t2 = d2.t2.astype('category')

# needs > 20GB of memory and takes for ever
piv2 = d2.pivot_table(values='dummy', index=['i1','i2'], columns=['t1','t2'])
```

I am wondering if this is expected and I am doing something wrong, or if this is a bug in pandas. Should dtype `category` for `str` not be very transparent (for this use case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. What's happening is [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) is calculating the Cartesian product of grouper categories.

This is a [known intended behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471648/pandas-groupby-with-categories-with-redundant-nan). In Pandas v0.23.0, we saw the introduction of the `observed` argument for [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Setting `observed=True` only includes observed combinations; it is `False` by default. This argument has <s>not yet</s> now been rolled out to related methods such as `pandas.pivot_table`. <s>In my opinion, it should be.</s>

But now let's *see* what this means. We can use an example dataframe and see what happens when we `print` the result.

#### Setup

We make the dataframe substantially smaller:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'t1': ["a","b","c"]*n, 't2': ["x","y","z"]*n,
                   'i1': list(range(int(n/2)))*6, 'i2': list(range(int(n/2)))*6,
                   'dummy':0})
```

#### Without categories

This is likely what you are looking for. Unobserved combinations of categories are not represented in your pivot table.

```
piv = df.pivot_table(values='dummy', index=['i1','i2'], columns=['t1','t2'])
print(piv)

t1     a  b  c
t2     x  y  z
i1 i2         
0  0   0  0  0
1  1   0  0  0
2  2   0  0  0
3  3   0  0  0
4  4   0  0  0
```

#### With categories

With categories, all combinations of categories, even unobserved combinations, are accounted for in the result. This is expensive computationally and memory-hungry. Moreover, the dataframe is dominated by `NaN` from unobserved combinations. It's probably *not* what you want.

**Update:** you can now set the [`observed`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) parameter to `True` to only show observed values for categorical groupers.

```
d2 = df.copy()
d2.t1 = d2.t1.astype('category')
d2.t2 = d2.t2.astype('category')

piv2 = d2.pivot_table(values='dummy', index=['i1','i2'], columns=['t1','t2'])
print(piv2)

t1       a           b            c         
t2       x   y   z   x    y   z   x   y    z
i1 i2                                       
0  0   0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0
   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
1  0   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   1   0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0
   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
2  0   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   2   0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0
   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
3  0   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   3   0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0
   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
4  0   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
   4   0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0 NaN NaN NaN  0.0
```

Comment: Thankfully, pivot_table now includes an 'observed' parameter (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Setting it to True allowed me to quickly create a pivot table with a categorical column. When it was set to False, my computer was using over 50 GB of memory while trying to create the table.