# Code to get a pivot table with pandas is using the whole memory with a relatively small input matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a code to get the pivot table from a dataframe with 44.000 samples, 4 columns (types string, categorical, categorical and int64). Despite the relatively small size, the whole 16GB RAM are used and the code apparently never ends.

I tried used very small chunks of the input matrix, and whereas slow, it can run. However, once I try an input matrix with +10k rows, it fails.

```py
pivottable = pd.pivot_table(finaldf, index= 'Visitor_ID', columns = 'catID', values='timecat')
```

`finaldf` is a 44k rows, 4 columns dataframe with fields `Visitor_ID`, categorical (~2k categories); `catID`, categorical (~5k categories); `timecat`, int64; and `Page URL`, string object not used for pivoting.

Given the small size of the input matrix I expected a quick run, specially given the machine is has an i7, 8th generation CPU.

Comment: That indeed sounds strange. Have you already tried to pre-aggregate your data? I mean to group it on "Visitor_ID" and "cat_ID" before pivoting the aggregated result? Maybe you could use that as a workaround.

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953074/pivot-table-requires-more-memory-if-dtype-is-category-memoryerror) may help shed some light - maybe try casting your categorical dtypes `.astype('O')` before pivoting

Comment: Thanks. I tried both proposed solutions (pre-aggregating and casting to ```.astype('O')```, but it did not work. I forgot to mention ```catID``` is categorical but with URL strings, which is maybe a reason for the problem. I changed it for a numerical categorical and it produced the desired result. There is still an issue because the 40k rows sample is a subset of the real dataset, at 2M rows. If I try to run it with the full dataset, it won't use but half the memory, but ~45 minutes run time already and no outcome.