# Python - groupby behaving oddly with 'category' type

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, categories

I'm troubleshooting some scripts that are crunching a large number of records, and occasionally throwing memory errors. The scripts worked fine on a laptop but this memory behavior started when we tried to port it to a server. I've largely gotten past this by doing a del command on a dataframe as soon as it's no longer needed, followed by gc.collect(). The server has Python version 3.6.9; my laptop has 3.7.

One trick that was suggested to me is to force the datatypes on the initial step, to be float32 instead of float64 (the default, as the data was being read in from a csv file). Similarly, a couple of integer fields are now forced to int16. And, a colleague suggested that yet another field, which was being treated as "object" but in reality is 2-characters and only has a few dozen values, should be treated as "category". The changes to float32 and int16 have reduced the size of the dataframe about 40%, so I think we're on the right track here.

I added all that to the script, then did a groupby command - and the 10,000 input records I was testing with ballooned to over 3 million. I looked at the output and it seems like it's producing output with every possible combination of the grouped fields.

Any ideas on why it behaves this way? I haven't had any luck finding out anything.

Sample code (and results) that show this behavior:

```
import pandas as pd
myd = {'item': ['001','002','001','001','001','002','002','002','001','001'], 
    'color': ['red','red','red','yellow','blue','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','red'],
    'selldate':['2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-02-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-02-01'],
    'howmany': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'cost': [1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00],
    'price':[2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00]
    }
mydf=pd.DataFrame(data=myd)   
mydf
```

Result:

```
  item   color    selldate  howmany  cost  price
0  001     red  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
1  002     red  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
2  001     red  2020-02-01        1   1.0    2.0
3  001  yellow  2020-02-01        1   1.0    2.0
4  001    blue  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
5  002  yellow  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
6  002  yellow  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
7  002  yellow  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
8  001  yellow  2020-02-01        1   1.0    2.0
9  001     red  2020-02-01        1   1.0    2.0
```

Groupby:

```
mydf.groupby(['item','color','selldate'], as_index=False)[['howmany', 
                   'cost', 'price']].sum()
```

Result (as expected):

```
  item   color    selldate  howmany  cost  price
0  001    blue  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
1  001     red  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
2  001     red  2020-02-01        2   2.0    4.0
3  001  yellow  2020-02-01        2   2.0    4.0
4  002     red  2020-01-01        1   1.0    2.0
5  002  yellow  2020-01-01        3   3.0    6.0
```

Changing the "color" column to "category":

```
mydf['color']=mydf['color'].astype('category')
mydf.groupby(['item','color','selldate'], as_index=False)[['howmany', 
                   'cost', 'price']].sum()
```

And the result is:

```
   item   color    selldate  howmany  cost  price
0   001    blue  2020-01-01      1.0   1.0    2.0
1   001    blue  2020-02-01      NaN   NaN    NaN
2   001     red  2020-01-01      1.0   1.0    2.0
3   001     red  2020-02-01      2.0   2.0    4.0
4   001  yellow  2020-01-01      NaN   NaN    NaN
5   001  yellow  2020-02-01      2.0   2.0    4.0
6   002    blue  2020-01-01      NaN   NaN    NaN
7   002    blue  2020-02-01      NaN   NaN    NaN
8   002     red  2020-01-01      1.0   1.0    2.0
9   002     red  2020-02-01      NaN   NaN    NaN
10  002  yellow  2020-01-01      3.0   3.0    6.0
11  002  yellow  2020-02-01      NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: add [`observed=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to the groupby call. This will also greatly speed up that operation.

Comment: Interesting! I added that to my snippet and it did produce the expected result. I'm scratching my head as to just why this behavior would be something anyone even wanted in this scenario. 

Then again, I'm a database person who has programmed in the past; the person who wrote the code is a statistician who has done limited programming work and doesn't know the database side. Neither of us are, obviously, Python experts!

Comment: The use cases are a bit limited, but you could imagine a categorical for like Monday-Sunday, and in that case you might want every row to appear if you were then going to calculate some `pct_change` throughout the week. (obv better to do with dates and `resample`). If it were my choice the default would be `observed=True` as there's more accidental harm with the current default. I've had code run for 5 hours because I accidentally forgot to add that and with `observed=False` it was trying to create a 40B+ row DataFrame. Switching to True the code ran in like 2 minutes.

Comment: I agree - the default ought to be observed=True. 

And I can see the value in the ability to force what is basically a placeholder entry for the others. 

Turns out my google-fu was faulty - very similar question answered some time back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471648/pandas-groupby-with-categories-with-redundant-nan

Would there be a performance benefit to using the field as a "category" vs leaving it as an object?

Comment: Pandas category dtypes have a lot of cons:
- group by output: the output of the groupby is very messy. a lof of Nan are generated depending on your categories values.
- the same problem applies to the filtering.
- concatenation issue with category type: the category type is linked to a dictionary of values so when you concatenate or merge you will have trouble and the loss of the category dtype.

You could have more in-depth information from this article: https://medium.com/gitconnected/pandas-category-type-pros-and-cons-1bcac1bdea71