# Grouping by columns returns all groups regardless prior filtering of values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Concept question:
I have a large dataframe (df) with 4M rows and 15 columns (col1 - col14 and Flag).
Please advise why the following is happening:

I am selecting the subset of interest:

```
temp = df.loc[(df['col1'].eq('a') & df['col13'].eq(113)), ['col1', 'col13', 'Flag']]
```

Trying to groupby and mean on Flag column and get all the groups col1-col2 with NaN on the Flag "mean" (Flag here is 0 or 1 integer):

```
temp.groupby(['col1', 'col13'])['Flag'].mean()
```

It seems that Python groupby ignores my filtering and returns all possible groups. Why is that?
Note, when I do the same for col1 and Flag, everything works perfectly.

Comment: I think problem is with categoricals, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471648/pandas-groupby-with-categories-with-redundant-nan)

Comment: These columns are categorical yes, should I convert them to objects?

Comment: You filtered for `['col1', 'col13', 'Flag']` but used `col2` in the `.groupby`. Is there a typo there? Could you try including `col2` in your subset of data? i.e. `temp = df.loc[(df['col1'].eq('a') & df['col13'].eq(113)), ['col1', 'col2', 'col13', 'Flag']]`

Comment: @kelvt yep fixed