# pandas group by week & get last week data as new df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that has the following, `df.dtypes`:

```
key                 object
date                datetime64[ns]
username            object
answer              object
grade               object
dtype: object
```

I then group by week:

```
test_lastweek = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT')])['key'].count()
```

I can see that that are 45 records that fall with in the last week of `2019-08-17`:

```
date
2019-06-29     475
2019-07-06     294
2019-07-13    2311
2019-07-20     389
2019-07-27     554
2019-08-03     408
2019-08-10     587
2019-08-17      45
Freq: W-SAT, Name: key, dtype: int64
```

**Question**: How do I get the last weeks data, all 45 records with the data from `df` and make that into a new df?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access pandas groupby dataframe by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

you can just filter the dataframe using .loc if you want all records from last week

```
df_last_week = df.loc[df['date'] >= '2019-08-17']
```

let me know if this helps.