# Iterate through each category in column and add values from another column as a separate df

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add for each category within the  `Customer_Acquisition_Channel`  column all values in  `Days_To_Acquisition`  column to a separate df.

All Customer_ID vales are unique in dataset below

DF

```
Customer_ID Customer_Acquisition_Channel  Days_To_Acquisition
323         Organic                       2
583         Organic                       5
838         Organic                       2
193         Website                       7
241         Website                       7
642         Website                       1
```

Desired Output:
Days_To_Acq_Organic_Df

```
Index Days_To_Acquisition
0     2
1     5
2     2
```

Days_To_Acq_Website_Df

```
Index Days_To_Acquisition
0     7
1     7
2     1
```

This is what I have tried so far, but I would like to use a for loop instead going through each column manually

```
sub_1 = df.loc[df['Customer_Acquisition_Channel'] == 'Organic']
Days_To_Acq_Organic_Df=sub_1[['Days_To_Acquisition']]

sub_2 = df.loc[df['Customer_Acquisition_Channel'] == 'Website']
Days_To_Acq_Website_Df=sub_2[['Days_To_Acquisition']]
```

Comment: have a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the result, but I think `pd.groupby` can help and combined with `agg` or `apply` with or without a `lambda` function or even with a list comprehension can help you get more out of the desired results.

Comment: `df_dict = {f'Days_To_Acquisition_{g}_df':k.drop('Customer_Acquisition_Channel', 1) for g,k in df.groupby('Customer_Acquisition_Channel')}` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through unique values of the channel column and create new dataframes, change the column names, and append them to a list:

```
dataframes = []
for channel in df.Customer_Acquisition_Channel.unique():
    new_df = df[df['Customer_Acquisition_Channel'] == channel][['Customer_ID','Days_To_Acquisition']]
    new_df.columns = ['Customer_ID',f'Days_To_Acquisition_{channel}_df']
    dataframes.append(new_df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
for df in dataframes:
    print(df,'\n__________')

   Customer_ID  Days_To_Acquisition_Organic_df
0          323                               2
1          583                               5
2          838                               2 
__________
   Customer_ID  Days_To_Acquisition_Website_df
3          193                               7
4          241                               7
5          642                               1 
__________
```

Alternatively, you can store the dataframes to a dictionary so you can name them and call them individually:

```
dataframes = {}
for channel in df.Customer_Acquisition_Channel.unique():
    new_df = df[df['Customer_Acquisition_Channel'] == channel][['Customer_ID','Days_To_Acquisition']]
    new_df.columns = ['Customer_ID',f'Days_To_Acquisition_{channel}']
    dataframes[f'Days_To_Acquisition_{channel}_df'] = new_df
```

OUTPUT:

```
print(dataframes['Days_To_Acquisition_Organic_df'])

   Customer_ID  Days_To_Acquisition_Organic
0          323                            2
1          583                            5
2          838                            2
```

Comment: How can I print only of the df's - lets say the first one? I get the following error when printing for example 'Days_To_Acquisition_Organic_df' --> error: name not defined

Comment: See my amended answer